# Oracle SQL Where clause to find date records older than 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to find records in a (Oracle SQL) table using the creation date field where records are older than 30 days. It would be nice to find records using a operators like > but if anyone can suggest quick SQL where clause statement to find records older than 30 days that would be nice. Please suggest Oracle syntax as that is what I am using.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE creation_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
```

SYSDATE returns the date & time; [TRUNC](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) resets the date to being as of midnight so you can omit it if you want the `creation_date` that is 30 days previous including the current time.

Depending on your needs, you could also look at using [ADD_MONTHS](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php):

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE creation_date <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)
```

Comment: I prefer `creation_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - interval '1' month` :)

Comment: @be here now: that's fine, as long as you don't mind if it fails with ORA-01839 "date not valid for month specified" in some cases, e.g. if creation_date is 31 March.

Comment: hm, I've always believed `interval` expression was designed to handle these situations correctly...

Comment: Should we trunc the creation date as will like `WHERE TRUNC(creation_date) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30` ?